# how to register custom aframe components in quasar based app?

Tags: vue.js, aframe, quasar, webpack-hmr

i try to use [Aframe](https://aframe.io/) in combination with [quasar](https://quasar.dev/) (that is build on vue.js).

in Aframe i can add custom components with [`AFRAME.registerComponent`](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/core/component.html#aframe-registercomponent-name-definition)

currently i use a vue-component to do this. and basically this is working fine.
but in development mode the HotModuleReplacement brings an issues:
the vue components is reloaded - and this way tries to re register the aframe components - that leads to this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: The component `xxxx` has been already registered. Check that you are not loading two versions of the same component or two different components of the same name.
```

i did not find any way to **un**register a component.

what is the best way to register my custom aframe components in my quasar based app?
or how can i unregister / cleanup `AFRAME.registerComponent` to allow for HMR?

Comment: I think, you could use the "[boot files](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files)" to registerComponent there which will only happen once, then reuse them in any vue components

Comment: @Chay22 thanks! yeah that is working. do you want to add it as answer?